# MS Office 2013 - Using revision mode in readOnly

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

My compagny just migrate from MS Office 2010 to Office 2013.
I 'm using a bunch of document located on a sharepoint with revision mode activated.

I need to read thoses documents and consult the revision history, but I want to avoid the use of modification mode because the document will be lock for other users.

Any way to use the revision mode in read only (default opening for ms Word 2013)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !
The revision menu is blocked by the protected mode and not the readonly mode.
So the easiest way is to disable the protected mode for content from potential unsafe places

To change de protected view parameters : http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-protected-view-microsoft-wor